# Xpages: very strange error page in browser

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpages app that is targeted for the browser. I was working with a fellow developer when my app encountered an error in the browser. The output was very odd:

[image]

The same error appears in XPiNC like this:

[image]

I have checked "Display Xpage Runtime Error". Am running 9.0.1 FP2 or FP3 on the server, with the latest but one Extension Library.

Comment: The first screenshot is an IIS error.

Comment: It looks like you are passing com.scoular.model.PC.loadbyUNID a parameter it's not set up for - can you confirm it's a string, not an object? Based on the name, it looks like you're passing a UNID string, and I think the browser error is saying it's an object.

Comment: Yes, this problem is in general because we have an IIS server sitting in front of Domino. I do not as yet know why the IIS server doesn't pass the error back to the browser, or rather why it doesn't pass the error from Domino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clean** your project and re**build** it. This helps often in cases when all is coded right but suddenly doesn't work anymore.

A good try is to restart http server with `restart task http` on server console too.